# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: html, json

Please any solution for this error. It is for a Chrome extension
this is the code manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "Volume",
"description": "this show the v",
"version": "1.0",
"host_permissions": \[
"https://www.googleapis.com/*"
\],
"content_scripts": \[
{
"matches": \["https://www.youtube.com/*"\],
"js": \["popup.js"\]
}
\],
"action": {
"default_popup": "popup.html"
}
}
```

and this the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vol</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Vol</h1>
  <p>wordss:</p>
  <input type="text" id="query" />
  <button id="checkPage">Buscar</button>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i don't know why this error appear

Comment: Browser is loading something that it thinks is JSON but it isn't (it is HTML instead). Maybe `manifest.json` is getting a 404 page (in HTML), or maybe you saved your HTML code as `manifest.json`...?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.